# Short story might be called "The Drifter" about a man who falls asleep on a bus in the 1940s and wakes up in the 1980s

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I am a librarian hoping to help a patron. The patron believes this science fiction/fantasy story was written in the 1960s by a housewife with four kids. The story might possibly be titled "The Drifter."  It's about a man who falls asleep on a bus in the 1940s and wakes up in the 1980s.  We have eliminated Shirley Jackson, Jack Finney, and Ray Bradbury.

Comment: Do you have more intel to give, I'm digging since a while now, and the closest I found was a time travel while sleeping, but no buses, no 40s/80s. But something with a golf club in the future. Really want to help

Comment: This is your second question that references a story "written in the 1960s by a housewife with four kids."   Perhaps a question focusing on this author will give better results?

Comment: The synopsis kind of reminded me of the '90's Outer Limits episode "Vanishing Act".  But I could find no evidence of that having been based on any short story.

Comment: It sounds like someone is trying to track down an anthology of memorable stories with SF/Fantasy elements which dated back to (approximately) the 1960s and were written by a woman who was supposedly a housewife with kids. It occurs to me that when I was a kid I enjoyed reading some library books which were collections of such stories by **Joan Aiken.** Her Wikipedia page says she had *two* children. http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?582 includes a list of all her story collections. Clicking on each one's link will show the titles of individual stories in that book, but no plot summaries.

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful comments! Please keep them coming. Yes, the two questions were intended to be read together, but Stack Exchange needed them to be separate.  Our patron asked about both stories as part of the same reference question. The above is actually all the intel I have.  I appreciate the Joan Aiken suggestion & will look into that (I like her too!), but not at all sure that is the answer.  I would like to hear about the time travel while sleeping--possibly might be what she's looking for, but anyway am interested as a reader myself!  Thanks again!

Comment: A real long shot. But a search on Worldcat lists a 1964 book "The Drifter" by a woman named Margot Bennett.  https://firstsearch-oclc-org.mcpl.idm.oclc.org/WebZ/FSQUERY?sessionid=fsapp2-43183-jyndzfj8-nbn2kx:entitypagenum=38:0:next=html/records.html:bad=html/records.html:format=BI:numrecs=10:searchtype=titleauthor:dbname=WorldCat:indexh1=ti=:termh1=%22drifter%22:indexh2=au=:termh2=%22Bennett%2C+Margot%2C%22

Comment: A search of Margot Bennett on Wikipedia shows she did have four children and wrote science fiction.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margot_Bennett_(writer)   But, her bibliography does not include this particular title in her listing and the Worldcat description does not list the plot.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I will pass on this information to our patron--it sounds promising!!